# Powershell 2 works 3 does not

Tags: powershell

Why does the code below return a date in power shell 2 but not in Powers hell 3 I assume it to do with the variable $dtmDate being clear once the form object is ended. but how to I have it return to be used?

Cheers

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 

$objForm = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form 

$objForm.Text = "Select a Date" 
$objForm.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(190,190) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True

$objForm.Add_KeyDown({
    if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
        {
            $dtmDate=$objCalendar.SelectionStart
            $objForm.Close()
        }
    })

$objForm.Add_KeyDown({
    if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
        {
            $objForm.Close()
        }
    })

$objCalendar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar 
$objCalendar.ShowTodayCircle = $False
$objCalendar.MaxSelectionCount = 1
$objForm.Controls.Add($objCalendar) 

$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})  
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog() 

if ($dtmDate)
    {
        Write-Host "Date selected: $dtmDate"
    }
```

Comment: `$global:dtmDate = $objCalendar.SelectionStart`. (No, I don't know the exact scoping rules, or if something changed between 2 and 3.)

Comment: Actually, it's very strange that the posted code worked in PS2.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, "something" changed between 2 and 3 (3.0+ runs on .NET DLR), and it affected scope rules for event actions

Comment: Cheers for the help. I would accept that Jeroen if ti was in a separate answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Changing scope of **$dtmDate**=$objCalendar.SelectionStart to at script/global makes the code to work on PS v3 host.

```
$script:dtmDate=$objCalendar.SelectionStart
```

Comment: Seeing as this was posted 2 hours before by some one else it hardly seems fair if i accepted it as an answer.